# Restoring .DMP files in Oracle 8.1

Tags: download

Where can I get the Oracle 8.1 setup?

I'm also looking for the steps involved in restoring .DMP files in Oracle 8.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want Oracle 8i ? Oracle 8i is obsolete and I doubt you can download from OTN.

To import, the syntax is

`imp <user>/<password> file=<dump-filename> full=y ignore=y`

More details on [Oracle Wiki](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+export+and+import)

Comment: imp (import) is backwardly compatible, so you should be able to load an 8i export into 9i/10g/11g